# javascript "slideit" function is not working for a header image slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am just trying to create a slideshow in my header and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in the coding to make my slideshow work. It has to be something really simple, but I cannot find it. Any ideas?

website is: http://www.daleandhannah.com/CMI/site/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="slideshow1.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="slideshow2.gif"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="thirdcar.gif"
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="firstcar.gif" name="slide" width="100" height="56" />
<script>
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, but please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as your question does not fit our format as it stands. Once you have read the faq you can edit your question to be more specific, that way you will be more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the ready made code for javascript slide show at http://top-answers.net/webdesign/javascript-image-slide-show.html Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have

```
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="slideshow1.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="slideshow2.gif"
```

http://www.daleandhannah.com/CMI/site/slideshow2.jpg is fine, but
http://www.daleandhannah.com/CMI/site/slideshow2.gif gives me a 404 Error.